# How to shoot light trail photos with iPhone?

Tags: digital, light

I would wonder if someone can tell me how to shoot (take / capture) a light trails photo with an iPhone? If someone don't know what's that, here's the the one which googled find for me,

[image]

Is it possible to take such a photo with iPhone? If not, then which camera is needed for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle you could, you just need an app that allows you to take multiple shots in a regular sequence without large gaps. Then you can stitch them using a software like those used for star trails. (E.g. [First google hit](http://www.startrails.de/html/software.html)). You will need something like a tripod to keep the phone steady.

Actually, there is an app that does the job for you, it's called [Slow Shutter Cam](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slow-shutter-cam/id357404131?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4). It automates the process described above, straight on the phone.

The better alternative is to use a real camera with manual controls, and take a long exposure.